# How Do I generate a Solution equation of this condition?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**:
Solution of the differential equation $$x=1+xy\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{x^2y^2}{2!}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2+\frac{x^3y^3}{3!}(\frac{dy}{dx})^3+\dot{}\dot{}\dot{}\dot{}\dot{}$$ Is?

**Attempt** : My first thought went to Taylor's Expansion and tried to find a function which follows $$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{x}{1!}f^{'}(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f^{"}(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f^{'''}(0)+\dot{}\dot{}\dot{}\dot{}\dot{}$$

My initial guesses frames out that it must be something like $y=\ln x$ or $xy=x^y$ type function nut i can't pin-point any with a convincing method. Any suggestions or procedure will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Consider the Taylor series of $e^t = 1 + t + \ldots$ and substitute $xy \frac{dy}{dx}$ for $t$. btw is it $\frac{dx}{dy}$ in the first term or is this a typo?

Comment: Typo corrected @Winther

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is the exponential function with the arguement $xy \frac{dy}{dx}$ so the equation is
\begin{eqnarray*}
x= e^{ xy \frac{dy}{dx}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Take logarithms & integrate ... we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y^2= (ln x)^2 +C 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks!